# Is it possible to generate .docx files without having MS Word installed?

Tags: c#, ms-word, google-docs-api, word-automation, ole-automation

I want to use "OLE automation" (or whatever it's called now) to generate a Word document.

I assume that it's possible to perform the following programmatically:

```
Set page size (height, width, margin vals)
Set font type/name, style, and size
Add page numbering
Add pages
Insert page breaks
```

What I'm not sure of is if I need to have MS Word on my system to do this (to have the necessary DLLs, perhaps)? I use Open Office (I like it, and it's free), but I reckon controlling the creation of docs programmatically is probably easier/better documented for MS Word than it is for Open Office and/or Libre Office - that's why I'm strongly considering making this "rendezvous with Redmond."

This question is tangentially related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748864/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-construct-an-open-office-document-from-two-ex)

If Google Docs is a possibility here, I'd be willing to have a "meeting with Mountain View" but I know nothing about that file format or whether it can be "automated" etc.

I need to end up with something that I can either convert to a PDF file or a DOCX file. Open Office can open DOCX and convert files to PDF, but I don't know about Google Docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found https://docx.codeplex.com/ to be very useful in dynamically building docx documents.

Comment: It's such a small library, I couldn't believe until I tried how useful it is, a lot easier than the official OpenXml sdk.

Comment: Now here, I think: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
it is possible. Check this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425
this is a library for open xml documents (*.docx, *.xlsx and powerpoint files)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can Use Openxml , also with openXml you can create Excel Pdf and ...

[Check This out](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666751/Use-OpenXML-to-create-a-Word-document-from-a-docx)

Comment: Thanks; based on the blog post here: http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/06/cathal-why-did-you-create-docx.html (accessible from the link in the accepted answer), DocX seems the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to generate document **by template**:
https://github.com/StasClick/DocumentGenerator

'DocumentGenerator' can generate one leaflet, multiple leaflets in one document or registers.

Comment: It looks intriguing, but I wish it showed an example of what it actually produces; its' hard for me to visualize what it's doing. e.g., is the first call referencing an existing document, or creating a new one. The code is so minimal, it's difficult to imagine it doing much...